# How can I find an item in a dataframe that is dependent on two values simultaneously in another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a big dataframe consisting of order number (REMISION), position of the item (UBQ) and then a number of columns describing the item, its weight, etc. I created a script which gives me a new order for UBQ for each one of the distinct orders (I worked only with REMISION and UBQ as these were the important columns for my algorithm) but now have to get the rest of the information back to know the description, amount, etc so that I can actually work with the result. Any idea of how one might do it?

So the first dataframe looks like this (this is a reduced version as the original has 17 columns):

```
PEDIDO

    REMISION    centro costos     código   UBQ  Cantidad
0   OE112963  2017CE5439-0001  110400320  C34A         4
1   OE112963  2017CE5439-0001  110400132  B22A         3
2   OE112963  2017CE5439-0001  110101841  B41A         5
3   OE112963  2017CE5439-0001  110200187  A27A         1
4   OE112963  2017CE5439-0001  110200435  A31A         1
5   OE112963  2017CE5439-0001  110200593  C50A         1
6   OE112963  2017CE5439-0001  110200906  B55A         1
7   OE112963  2017CE5439-0001  110200907  B33A         1
8   OE112963  2017CE5439-0001  110200911  B46A         1
9   OE112963  2017CE5439-0001  110200939  E18A         2
10  OE112963  2017CE5439-0001  110200943  E13A         2
11  OE112963  2017CE5439-0001  110200975  C25A         1
12  OE112963  2017CE5439-0001  110200976  E14A         2
13  OE112963  2017CE5439-0001  110200977  C28A         2
14  OE112963  2017CE5439-0001  110200978  E15A         1
15  OE112963  2017CE5439-0001  110201053   B5A         2
16  OE112963  2017CE5439-0001  110201105  B43A         5
17  OE112963  2017CE5439-0001  110200894  B42A         2
18  OE112963  2017CE5439-0001  110102183  B61A         1
19  OE112963  2017CE5439-0001  110102260  A43A         1
20  OE112963  2017CE5439-0001  110102261  A40A         1
21  OE112963  2017CE5439-0001  110102264  A28A         1
22  OE112963  2017CE5439-0001  150206801   A1A         6
23  OE112963  2017CE5439-0001  180600064  B19A        36
24  OE112964  2017CE5539-0001  150206801   A1A         1
25  OE112964  2017CE5539-0001  190900689  B19A         3
26  OE112965  2017CE5539-0002  150206801   A1A         1
27  OE112965  2017CE5539-0002  180600064  B19A         4
28  OE112966  2017CE5539-0003  150206801   A1A         1
29  OE112966  2017CE5539-0003  190900689  B19A         4
30  OE112967  2017CE5539-0004  180600064  B19A         4
31  OE112968  2017CE5539-0005  180600064  B19A         4
32  OE112969  2018CE2439-0002  190900689  B19A         8
33  OE112970  2018CG3039-0002  110400320  C34A         3
34  OE112970  2018CG3039-0002  110400414   C3A        10
```

Now, the new dataframe has the order in UBQ changed like this

```
devol:

    REMISION    centro costos     código   UBQ  Cantidad
0   OE112963                               A1A          
1   OE112963                               B5A          
2   OE112963                              B19A          
3   OE112963                              B22A          
4   OE112963                              A27A          
5   OE112963                              A31A          
6   OE112963                              C34A          
7   OE112963                              B33A          
8   OE112963                              A28A          
9   OE112963                              A40A          
10  OE112963                              A43A          
11  OE112963                              B46A          
12  OE112963                              B42A          
13  OE112963                              B41A          
14  OE112963                              B43A          
15  OE112963                              B55A          
16  OE112963                              B61A          
17  OE112963                              C28A          
18  OE112963                              C25A          
19  OE112963                              E13A          
20  OE112963                              E14A          
21  OE112963                              E15A          
22  OE112963                              E18A          
23  OE112963                              C50A          
24  OE112964                               A1A          
25  OE112964                              B19A          
26  OE112965                               A1A          
27  OE112965                              B19A          
28  OE112966                               A1A          
29  OE112966                              B19A          
30  OE112967                              B19A          
31  OE112968                              B19A          
32  OE112969                              B19A          
33  OE112970                               C3A          
34  OE112970                              C17A
```

So now i need to fill the rest of the columns with the cost center, product code, amount, etc of the corresponding order number and position number to be able to use it again. It should look something like this:

```
    REMISION    centro costos     código   UBQ  Cantidad
0   OE112963  2017CE5439-0001  150206801   A1A         6
1   OE112963  2017CE5439-0001  110201053   B5A         2
2   OE112963  2017CE5439-0001  190900689  B19A        36
```

Do you know if there's a way to do this for all missing columns? (there are 12 other columns for which I need to fill this information as well)

Comment: Please take a look at [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: You could give `DataFrame.Merge()` a shot. Assuming your original dataframe is named `pedido` and your new dataframe is named `devol`: `df = devol.merge(pedido, on=['REMISION','UBQ'], right_suffix='_devol', left_suffix='_pedido', how='left')` That will bring columns from both dataframes together where the `REMISION` and `UBQ` columns match. It will rename any columns that are named the same with those suffixes so you know which column came from where. Then it's just a matter of keeping the columns you want and renaming them to drop their suffix (if I'm understanding you correctly).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @JNevill Thank you! It repeated some values in the merged dataframe but I just dropped duplicates and it worked perfectly, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

While as commented by @JNevill you could use `merge` to refill the dataframe, it would be better to not need to fill it in the first place.

First you will need to define the order you want for your UBQ as a list(note that the order is the order you will have later in the dataframe)

```
ubq_order = ['A1A','B5A','B19A','B22A','A27A','A31A','C34A','B33A',
             'A28A','A40A','A43A','B46A','B42A','B41A','B43A','B55A',
             'B61A','C28A','C25A','E13A','E14A','E15A','E18A','C50A']
```

Then you can define a custom sorting function for pandas

```
def custom_sorting(col: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    if col.name == "REMISION":
        return col
    elif col.name == 'UBQ':
        return col.map({v:i for i,v in enumerate(ubq_order)})
```

with it you can the sort your dataframe using

```
df.sort_values(by=['REMISION', 'UBQ'], inplace=True,key=custom_sorting)
```

which will preserve all the other entries.